# Rails + React js + react-rails gem submit form with single component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, reactjs

I am trying to submit form in react js with Rails.

I am new to React js and it is my first app

I am getting error No route matches [POST] "/"

Using single component(jsx) to submit the form.I am getting routing error.

Following is my code

**EDIT**

I changed the route and now I got error **"InvalidAuthenticityToken in ItemsController#create"**

How can i raise or alert variable in in jsx file ?

I add following route in route.rb

```
 resources :items
 root :to => redirect("/items")
```

ItemsController

```
 def index
    @presenter = { :action => items_path,
            :csrf_token => request_forgery_protection_token,
            :csrf_param => form_authenticity_token
        }
 end    

def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.save
end

private

def item_params      
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :price)            
end
```

Index.html.erb

```
 <%= react_component('Form1', {:presenter => @presenter.to_json}, {:presenter => true})%>
```

Form1.js.jsx

```
 var Form1 = React.createClass({
    handeSubmit: function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    // var form = e.target;
    // var name = form.querySelector('[name="item[name]"]').value;
    // var price = form.queySelector('[name="item[price]"]').value; 


    var name = this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value.trim();
    var price = this.refs.price.getDOMNode().value.trim();

    if(!name || !price)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var formData = $( this.refs.form.getDOMNode() ).serialize();
    var action = this.props.presenter.action
    // alert({formData});


    $.ajax({    
      data: formData,
      url: action,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",

    });

},




render: function(){
    return (
        <form ref="form" className="" action={ this.props.presenter.action } acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
            <input type="hidden" name={ this.props.presenter.csrf_param } value={ this.props.presenter.csrf_token } />
            <input ref="name" name="item[name]"  /><br/>
            <input ref="price" name="item[price]" /><br/>
            <button type="submit"> Submit</button> 
        </form>


    )
}

});
```

Comment: Hard to tell from the limited code here... is your items controller set up as a resource?  have you verified that `action = '/items'` when sent to the ajax call?

Comment: Everything there looks right. Could you share your `routes.rb`? Maybe the route to `create` is missing?

Comment: @gravityplanx Thanks and Please find my edit

Comment: @rmosolgo thanks please find my edit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for AJAX requests, you should send the CSRF token as a header, not as a form field.

(Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper.html#method-i-csrf_meta_tags)

Here's how you could add that header in your case:

```
var csrfToken = this.props.presenter.csrf_token; 

$.ajax({    
  data: formData,
  url: action,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  // Before sending, add the CSRF header:
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
  },
});
```

Does that work for you?

By the way, one way I work around this is by using `react_component` for form *fields*, but using Rails' `form_for` to make the actual `<form>` tag. For example,

```
<%= form_for @item, remote: true do |f| %>
  <!-- Rails will add CSRF token -->
  <%= react_component("ItemFormFields", item: @item) %>
<% end %>
```